# Upload file using Fetch and calc the progress using readable streams not work as expected (Browser)

Tags: node.js, browser, fetch, fetch-api

I am trying to upload a file using fetch streams, I need can calculate the upload progress.

But on the server I receive an corrupt file of 0 bytes, I really don't know how to use the ReadableStreams feature, that is a really new feature.

Client (Browser)

```js
const fileReadble = (reader) => new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
     return pump()
      function pump() {
        return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
          if (done) {
              controller.close()
              return
          }
        
          controller.enqueue(value)
          return pump()
        })
      }
  }

const uploadVideo = async (file) => {
    const fileReader = file.stream().getReader()
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3005', { 
      method: 'POST',   
      body: fileReadble(fileReader),
    })
  
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.error(`unexpected response ${response.statusText}`)
      return
    }
}
})
```

Server (Node)

```js
import http from 'node:http'
import { createWriteStream } from 'node:fs'

http
  .createServer((req) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') return
    req.pipe(createWriteStream('./video.mp4'))
  })
  .listen(3005)
```

Note: I am using tus-js-client on the server to upload videos to vimeo, this is for security reasons, I need to send the file using Fetch.

Comment: Does your browser support sending `ReadableStream`s? According to [this post](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/) Chrome 95 supports it but I've tested the newest one (98) and the newest Firefox (96.0.3) and they both fail. They fail the feature detection in mentioned post too so it's not my bad code. I tested it by sending `blob` (works) vs `blob.stream()` (sends `[object ReadableStream]` string).

Comment: Seems like streaming uploads is just getting implemented now in Chrome, apparently will be out in Chrome 105 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688906#c77